# integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a^2x^2}}{1+e^{x+\eta}} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I've encountered the following integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a^2x^2}}{1+e^{x+\eta}} dx$$

I tried mathematica, but it cannot be solved. I also tried by setting $a$ and $\eta$ to be different numbers, but mathematica still returns no results. Is this because the integral is not convergent for any vales of $a$ and $\eta$?

If this integral is convergent with certain restraint for $a$ and $\eta$, can anyone help derive this integral?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The integral is convergent for every $a\neq 0$, since $|f(x)| \leq e^{-a^2 x^2}$ (being $f$ the integrand).

Comment: but as x goes to $-\infty$, the denominator $e^{x+\eta}$ goes to 0, making  the quotient goes to $\infty$ right? In this case, it cannot be convergent(?)

Comment: $1+e^t > 1$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: oh yes you are right!  thanks!!  Any more suggestions for deriving this integral?

Comment: I keep wondering why people are upvoting questions without any context (there are infinitely many integrals, why could anybody be interested in that one?!) and the single "effort" of asking Mathematica, and then, asking stack exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\eta=0$
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-a^2 x^2}}{1+e^{x}}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-a^2 x^2}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^x}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-a^2 x^2}\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a}$$
and a similar approach can be applied when $\eta\neq 0$:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-a^2 x^2}}{1+e^{x+\eta}}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-a^2 (x-\eta)^2}}{1+e^x}\,dx = e^{-a^2\eta^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a^2 x^2}\left(\frac{e^{2a^2\eta x}}{1+e^x}+\frac{e^{-2a^2\eta x}}{1+e^{-x}}\right)\,dx $$
in combination with a geometric series expansion:
$$ \frac{e^{\pm 2a^2\eta x}}{1+e^{\pm x}}=\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m e^{\pm(2a^2\eta+m)x},\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-a^2 x^2}\cosh(\mu x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a}\,e^{\frac{\mu^2}{4a^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks Jack! Your information is so important! This integral comes from the marginal mean of response (Yij) for a random effect logistic model with an assumption of Gaussian distribution in longitudinal analysis.  I want to keep the problem expression straightforward and concise therefore did not talk much about the background. I also tried algebra derivation, but the way I only came up with is to use $x+\eta=w$, $e^(w)=u$, but after replacement, the integral is even more complicated. I was told that mathmatica may help, but no output when using it.

Comment: @t.hu: I added a line for clarifying that part.

Comment: I understand the first part and derived the result as a sum (m=0,1,2..., this series seems divergent though), but I do not understand the second part, how $coshx(\mu x)$ relates to this integral? do you mean $cosh(\mu x)=e^{\mu x}/(1+e^x)+e^{-\mu x}/(1+e^{-x})$, I tried to derive from $coshx(x)=(e^x+e^{-x})/2$ but cannot make the two equated?

Comment: @t.hu: when you expand both $\frac{e^{+2a^2\eta x}}{1+e^{+x}}$ and $\frac{e^{-2a^2\eta x}}{1+e^{-x}}$ and collect back $e^{-mx}$ and $e^{mx}$ you get a $e^{-mx}+e^{mx}= 2\cosh(mx)$.

Comment: Thanks Jack!!!! I derived the final result: the integral $=c\sum_{m>0}(-1)^{m}e^{\frac{(m+2\eta a^2)^2}{4a^2}}$. Is this series a convergent one? I feel like it is divergent, because the sequence $e^{\frac{(m+2\eta a^2)^2}{4a^2}}$ goes to infinity as m grows, and the difference for m, m-1 (f(m)-f(m-1)) grows as m grows, therefore, this integral is a divergent one for any $\eta$. however, this is contradicting with the fact that this integral is convergent when $\eta=0$??

Comment: @t.hu: you have to be careful in applying the dominated convergence theorem for switching $\sum$ and $\int$: in this case you simply cannot. But the idea of approximating $\frac{e^{2a^2\eta x}}{1+e^x}+\frac{e^{-2a^2\eta x}}{1+e^{-x}}$ with a (finite!) combination of hyperbolic cosines produces decent approximations. For better approximations, I suggest to employ Laplace's method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59357/discussion-between-t-hu-and-jack-daurizio).